# To how convert protobuf object to ByteArray and the encode with Base64 URL_SAFE in Swift?

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, protocol-buffers

In Android, I could convert an object to ByteArray and then encode it to Base64 (URL_SAFE) as per code below

```
    val myByteArrayObject = protobufObject.toByteArray()
    val meEncodedObject = android.util.Base64.encodeToString.encodeToString(
          myByteArrayObject, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT).trim()
```

How could I achieve that in Swift?

Comment: I don't think that there is an embedded way in swift. You can try writing all the fields of the object into the bytearray.

Comment: Why downvote my question? It is a legitimate question where I ask around some iOS folks, and search on the web, not finding answer.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I'm sending a Protobuf Object from client to the server. Looks like the `toByteArray()` is the protobuf model api. Apparently the Java generated code does have it (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial), but not the swift generated protobuf code :(

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I found the answer and posted it. It's a very tricky condition in the protobuf model swift code that embed this undocumented public API one could access. And the name is totally different as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

```
do {
    let protobufSerialized = try protobufObject.serializedData()
    let protobufEncoded = protobufSerialized.base64EncodedString()

    // Do whatever need to be done with the protobufEncoded
} catch {  }
```

The main hidden function that is hard to find is `serializedData()` that exist on `SwiftProtobuf.Message`